# Objects in Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

This has been asked a couple times, but the examples didn't help a whole lot.

I want to post 'posts' to my server, so I have a 'posts' model and then a 'single' model. The 'posts' model represents all the posts, and then my 'single' model represents what each post needs... I am new to Ember.js, and really could use a hand here/direction.

So when I submit the form (for creating a new post):

```
// When the form is submitted, post it!
actions: {
// createNew begin
createNew() {
  var title = this.controller.get('title');
  var content = this.controller.get('content');

  const data = {
    "posts": [
      {
      "title": title,
      "content": content
      }
    ]
  };
  return this.store.createRecord('posts', data).save().
    then(function(post) {
      console.log(post);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
} // end of createNew
}
```

'posts' model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    posts: DS.hasMany('single'),
});
```

'single' model:
import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

And then my serializer to hook the two together...

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    posts: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

Currently, this is the error that outputs:

"Assertion Failed: All elements of a hasMany relationship must be instances of DS.Model, you passed [[object Object]]"

**In Short**: I need to create data models that can represent the following JSON structure:

```
{

"posts": [

    { "title": "Title", "content": "Content" }

 ]

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually saying exactly what's wrong.

> "Assertion Failed: All elements of a hasMany relationship must be instances of DS.Model, you passed [[object Object]]"

The model `posts` has a `hasMany` relationship to the model `single`. 
What your code is doing is passing a plain JS object instead of the model.

```
const data = {
  "posts": [
    {                    // <-
      "title": title,    // <-
      "content": content // <- this is a POJO
    }                    // <-
  ]
};
```

One way to solve this actually is to create the two objects separately.

```
// create 'posts' and 'single' separately
const posts = this.store.createRecord('posts');
const single = this.store.createRecord('single', {
  title,
  content
});
// link them up
posts.get('posts').addObject(single);
```

Comment: So this works, I believe, but my server throws a 400 error; leading me to think the content isn't formatted correctly.. {"errors":[{"post":["Must be an object"]},{"post.title":["Must be a string"]},{"post.content":["Must be a string"]}]}

Comment: "leading me to think" isn't giving me any useful information to help. You should inspect the network and actually see what is being sent and where exactly does the error happen (which code on the server and/or client). One idea is that you are not serializing the content properly when sending. Check what does `posts.toJSON()` return.